# jQuery append to adjacent element

Tags: jquery

Here's the structure.

```
<div>
  <a>Blah</a>
  <span>5</span>
</div>
<div>
  <a>Blah</a>
  <span>6</span>
</div>
```

and here's what I want

```
<div>
  <a>Blah<span>5</span></a>
</div>
<div>
  <a>Blah<span>6</span></a>
</div>
```

here's what I tried

```
$("div span").appendTo("a", this);
```

but I ended up with both spans landing in both a elements.

Comment: Use `.append` instead of `.appendTo` ?

Comment: You'll have to use .each for this, otherwise you'll have no access to `this`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("div span").each(function () {
    $(this).appendTo($(this).prev('a'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Not quite as elegant as koala's answer but this is what I came up with:

```
$('div span').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('a').append($(this).detach());
});
```

[Working Demo (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/HLczB/1/)

Comment: not as elegant, but less prone to breaking later. typo? `this.parent()`

Answer (score -2):

```
var span = "<span></span>";
$("div a").append(span);
```

or try this

```
var span = "<span></span>";
$("div a").html(span);
```

`FIDDLE`